# How to store the value of a variable Ansible in a loop?

Tags: ansible

I want to store the value of `{{ item }}` of the `loop` in a variable.

This is my task :

```yaml
include_role:
    name: role1
vars:
    template_path: "inventories/{{ ENV }}/group_vars/all"
    template_name: "wlc_wlb"
loop: "{{ range(1, ihs_number+2) | list }}"
```

Answer (score 1):

> ***I want to store the value of `{{ item }}` of the `loop` in a variable.***

A minimal example playbook

```yaml
---
- hosts: localhost
  become: false
  gather_facts: false

  tasks:

  - debug:
      msg: "{{ index }}"
    vars:
      index: "{{ item }}"
    loop: "{{ range(0, 10, 1) }}"
```

will result into an output of

```yaml
TASK [debug] *****************
ok: [localhost] => (item=0) =>
  msg: '0'
ok: [localhost] => (item=1) =>
  msg: '1'
ok: [localhost] => (item=2) =>
  msg: '2'
ok: [localhost] => (item=3) =>
  msg: '3'
ok: [localhost] => (item=4) =>
  msg: '4'
ok: [localhost] => (item=5) =>
  msg: '5'
ok: [localhost] => (item=6) =>
  msg: '6'
ok: [localhost] => (item=7) =>
  msg: '7'
ok: [localhost] => (item=8) =>
  msg: '8'
ok: [localhost] => (item=9) =>
  msg: '9'
```

**Documentation**

- [Understanding variable precedence](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/playbook_guide/playbooks_variables.html#understanding-variable-precedence)

  > *17. task vars (only for the task)*